# How to update hyperlink field in SharePoint on prem doc library

Tags: powershell, document-library, sharepoint-on-prem, flow, 2019

I am working with SP On Prem 2019. In one of the document libraries, I have about 440 files which has a metadata field of type 'hyperlink' called 'Main Letter'. This hyperlink field contains link to a document in same library.

Out of 440 Files, there are about 8-9 hyperlinks used for tagging as metadata, sample display text of these hyperlinks are as below:

1. Document Revised Update 8
2. LCA Updated
3. Initial Proposal I

So maybe using PowerShell, I want to grab the rows where 'Main Letter' display text is 'LCA Updated' and update the URL to what I supply in like www.google.com and the same I can do for the remaining 7-8 hyperlink display texts as well.

Can someone please help me with script or flow that I can run, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below script to Update the Hyperlink field. Hope this may help you!

```
$SiteURL="<SiteUrl>"
$ListName = "<Document Library>"
$FieldName = "URL"

$hyperLinkDisplayText = "Support Center"
$hyperLinkOldURL = "/sites/support" #Here you provide the old url which you want to search
$hyperLinkNewURL = "/sites/supportV2"  #Here you provide the New url which you want to Replace

$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$List = $Ctx.Web.lists.GetByTitle($ListName)


#Define the CAML Query to Filter by Hyperlink value and Get List Item
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$Query.ViewXml = "@
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq >
                <FieldRef Name='$FieldName' /><Value Type='URL'>$hyperLinkOldURL</Value>
            </Contains >
        </Eq>
    </Query>
</View>"

$ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
$Ctx.Load($ListItems)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

If($ListItems.Count -gt 0)
{
    ForEach($Item in $ListItems)
    {
        $HyperLinkField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue]$Item[$FieldName]
        $HyperLinkField.Url = $hyperLinkNewURL
        $HyperLinkField.Description = $HyperlinkDescription

        #Update Hyperlink Field
        $Item[$FieldName] = $HyperLinkField
        $Item.Update()
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        Write-host "Hyperlink Field Value Updated in Link List!" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
Else
{
    Write-host "Hyperlink Field Value '$($hyperLinkOldURL)' Not Found in Link List!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Krunal, appreciate it. I ran the script and it worked well. However it also updated the display text of the hyperlink field to the new url, is there a way to not update display text ?

Comment: Any thoughts, Krunal?

Comment: As you know the display text, you can add the same text in the description field